# How can I type a £ (pound sign character) on my iMac?

Tags: osx-lion, logitech-keyboard

How can I type a £ character on my iMac using my US Logitech keyboard. I am on Lion. It worked on my MacBook.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you use the same *Input Source* on both systems. Open *System Preferences » Language & Text* to find out.

[image]

---

This window also allows you to *Show Input menu on menu bar*. From there, you can *Show Keyboard Viewer*, a handy utility that shows you what character pressing a combination of regular and modifier keys (`Option`, `Shift`) will produce.

Press any modifier to change what's displayed. For example, pressing `Shift` will show that the *British* keyboard layout will produce `£` when pressing `Shift-3`.

[image]

Comment: @BlueCedar You're welcome. Remember to click the checkmark next to my answer to mark your question answered.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> should do it.  This works on US keyboard settings without modifying anything, out of the box.  £!  If you are using a mac labeled keyboard, it will be <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>

Comment: Today, as far as I can tell, on my Macbook Pro with a US keyboard setting, you need the "fn" key to press Alt as described here and (fn)Alt+3 will do a £.  I'm using El Capitan and I get no answer at all from option+ 1 thru 5.  I can get a € symbol though, from Shift+Alt+2, but it looks like some change was made in 2015.

I have no idea why you can't get this symbol using the Option key alone, it was very hard to find this solution.

Comment: I'm on Sierra, on a current macbook pro, and nothing is different for me. £ is still Option-3.

Comment: Today I (El Capitan) tried pressing Option-1 thru 5 and noticed that if you have multiple desktops, it changes desktops.  I can't even get a pound sign at all.  Maybe it would work if I didn't have a Desktop #3 open.  I haven't updated my OS since I posted that two weeks ago.

Comment: That is a third party application or a manually created shortcut.

Comment: No it's not either (third party or manually created), but thank you for pointing me in that direction as it is a Mission Control shortcut that can be disabled.  ££ fn+option (= alt) + 3 = £

Works alright now!

Comment: Hooray! I'd love to know how option-3 got populated into a mission control shortcut, that is not on my fresh sierra or high sierra installs. Glad you got it working, ¡™£¢∞§¶ to you!